# Different types of functions as arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c, function, arguments

I am writing a program where I need to use different functions for different cases and I need to use these functions extensively. So, I was thinking that the best way to do that is to pass functions as arguments. Both are **double** functions. However, the number of arguments needed for each function is different. How should I do that? I give a basic scenario of the program below.

```
if (A > B){
func(double x, double y, double func_A(double a1, double a2));
}else{
func(double x, double y, double func_B(double b1, double b2, double b3));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can overload the function `func` to take different callbacks as parameters:

```
double func_A(double a1, double a2)
{
    return 0;
}
double func_B(double a1, double a2, double a3)
{
    return 0;
}

typedef double (*FUNCA)(double,double);
typedef double (*FUNCB)(double,double,double);

void func(double x, double y, FUNCA)
{
}
void func(double x, double y, FUNCB)
{
}

int main()
{
    func(0,0,func_A); //calls first overload
    func(0,0,func_B); //calls second overload
}
```

Comment: but then i'll have to define func separately for func_A and func_B, right? it'll be too much lengthy for me and i'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @PopulationXplosive then you can't, because the two are different types.

Comment: :( thanks. does any other programming language have this functionality?

Comment: How are you going to define the functions without knowing which parameters they take?

Comment: @CorporalTouchy I think he knows what parameters they take.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But how is he going to avoid defining them separately?

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading is allowed in C++, so just use it. Luchian Grigore has given you an example

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to have overloads of func call a simple implementation function that accepts separate pointers to `double(double, double)` and `double(double, double, double)`, the inapplicable one will be NULL...

```
void func_impl(double x, double y, double (*f)(double, double), double (*g)(double, double, double))
{
    ...
    if (...)
         f(a, b);
    else
         g(a, b, c);
    ...
}

void func(double x, double y, double (*f)(double, double))
{
    func_impl(x, y, f, NULL);
}

void func(double x, double y, double (*g)(double, double, double))
{
    func_impl(x, y, NULL, g);
}

void caller(...)
{
    ...
    if (A > B)
        func(x, y, func_A);
    else
        func(x, y, func_B);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a nice idea. But, the thing is that I will be using func_A and func_B without any conditional statements. It's like I use a function, say func_type, throughout the func_impl. It may be func_A or func_B, depending on the condition. So, the problem is how will I use a single variable to address either func_A or func_B within the func_impl. Also, the variables of both func_A and func_B will be changing throughout func_impl.